# ArcSDE version status stuck in 33554433

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, enterprise-geodatabase, versioning

One of our ArcSDE versions (esri v10.1 and oracle 11g) in SDE.Versions table  shows a 'status' field value of 33554433 instead of the usual 0, 1, 2 for private, public, protected. I understand this is one the SDE workflow status that shows the actual current status of the version in the version's editing processes as discussed here : https://community.esri.com/thread/47331
We have reconciled and posted this version successfully but the status does not seem to change!  Also running the query to show the compression blocking version, shows this as version as the one blocking the compression.
I understand editing the SDE versions table is not a good practice, but I don't see much documentation on how to change the status.  Any advise would be welcome.

Comment: contact esri support for walkthrough. as manually deleting versions can lose or corrupt the database, do you have a backup?

Comment: walkthrough for?  I am not asking to delete any versions manually.  I know Delete Version tool can be used for that.

Comment: I did confer with ESRI support and they confirmed 33554433 is by design. They have advised into looking at the STATE_ID sequence and tracking the ones that are inherited from DEFAULT version related edits